# Change background color of page when scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the background color of a webpage from black to white when you scroll to a certain point. Then change back when you scroll back up and repeat the process. I have code that adds a class to a block when you scroll to a certain point but I cant get the background color to change. Here is the jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function() {

        $('#block-yui_3_17_2_32_1488831533357_14601').each(function() {

            var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop(),

                bottomOfWindow = topOfWindow + $(window).height();

            var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

            if (imagePos <= bottomOfWindow - 100 && imagePos >= topOfWindow - 250) {

                $(this).addClass('color Change');

            } else {

                $(this).removeClass('colorChange');

            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.colorChange {
    #page {
        background-color: white;
        animation-name: colorChange;
        -webkit-animation-name: colorChange;

        animation-duration: 2s;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;

        animation-timing-function: ease;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;

        animation-iteration-count: 1;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;

        visibility: visible !important;
    }
}

@keyframes colorChange {
    0% {
        background-color: white;
    }
    100% {
        background-color: black;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes colorChange {
    0% {
        background-color: white;
    }
    100% {
        background-color: black;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I tried changing the if statement to change the color on the scroll position instead of adding a class that changes the color but it didn't work. Also how would I add an ease to the color change this way? Here is the edited code:

```
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function() {

        $('#block-yui_3_17_2_32_1488831533357_14601').each(function() {

            var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop(),

                bottomOfWindow = topOfWindow + $(window).height();

            var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

            if (imagePos <= bottomOfWindow - 100 && imagePos >= topOfWindow - 250) {

                $("#page").css("background-color", "black");
            } else {

                $("#page").css("background-color", "white");

            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would look better:

```
body {
    background: black; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(black, white); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(black, white); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(black, white); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(black, white); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

But, if you really have your heart set on that:

```
$(document).scroll( function () {
    rgb = $(document).scrollTop(); // just divide this number by however slow you want the effect to take place.
    $(document).css("background","rgb(" + rgb + ", " + rgb + ", " + rgb + ")");
} );
```

Comment: #block-yui_3_17_2_32_1488831533357_14601 is is an element towards the bottom of the screen. I want the background color of the page to change to black when you scroll down to the point. So that everything past that element in on a black background. I want it to change back to white when you scroll up past the element. And I want it to be done with an ease.

Comment: Maybe do something like: rgb = $(document).scrollTop() - $("#block-yui_3_17_2_32_1488831533357_14601").scrollTop() .  Add an if that checks if rgb is less than 0, and if it is, assign rgb to 0.